# Cakephp run cakephp shell in browser for debug purpose

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, console, cakephp-2.0

I have a CakePHP 2.x shell setup like this:

```
/var/www/flat/app/Console/Command/ReminderShell.php
```

and to run it I will call

```
/var/www/flat/app/Console/cake reminder daily_reminder
```

it will work out fine e.g

```
$listOfUser = $this->User->find('first', array(
    'recursive' => 1,
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.deleted' => 0,
        'User.locked'  => 0,
        'Group.deleted' => 0,
        'Group.locked' => 0,
    )
));
$this->out(print_r($listOfUser, true));
```

This will print a list of user, in array style like `cakephp` debug.

The problem is it's so hard to debug due to if the list is pretty long, command line will cut the top half. Is there anyway to open this in browser? how to point the url? and also can we use debug(); command too like normal in controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pipe your output to `less`:

```
/var/www/flat/app/Console/cake reminder daily_reminder | less
```

Or redirect to a file that you can open with your preferred editor later:

```
/var/www/flat/app/Console/cake reminder daily_reminder > daily_reminder.log
```